# How to generate multiple css files from separate scss source files arranged per component?

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass

I have the following vue component **Test.vue** an would like to split up this css into test.css along with my other component **Home.vue**'s css to be home.css. However everything compiles into app.css and merges everything.

```
<style lang='scss'>

    h2 {
        color: 1px solid red;
    }

</style>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'test',
    }

</script>

<template>
    <div class='Test'>
        <h2>test</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am using this to build an html and css compiler for another project so I don't have to code in it, but rather just copy the structure from the prod html+css from this vue build. This way I can just copy over these separate test.css and home.css files to my other system. Right now though, it combined styles and there's no per component decoupling of styles.

I don't really know where to start in splitting up the css, I've been googling for hours.

current:

```
dist
--/css
----app.css
```

desired:

```
dist
--/css
----app.css
----test.css
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Vue Webpack loader's documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/extract-css.html) suggests using `mini-css-extract-plugin` for Webpack 4 or `extract-text-webpack-plugin` for Webpack 3. Have you tried using that?

Comment: Yes I spent hours on it. Webpack drives me insane, absolutely no clue what I'm doing. I just want a few different separate CSS files -_-

Comment: Never did it myself so I can't help further... I had just quickly skimmed that part of the doc and thought I'd share it.